# Записать ключи словаря в csv

Tags: python, файлы, pandas, csv

```
import pandas as pd

dict_of_right_transitions = {
(0,1):'1',
(0,2):'2',
(0,6):'3',
(1,2):'4',
(1,3):'5',
(1,4):'6',
(1,5):'7',
(1,7):'8'
}
z = pd.DataFrame(list(dict_of_right_transitions.keys()), columns=['first status', 'second status'])
print(z)
z.to_csv(r"C:\\Users\\Users\\PyProj\\Script_check\\dict_of_right_transitions.csv")
```

***Вывод***

```
    first status  second status
0              0              1
1              0              2
2              0              6
3              1              2
4              1              3
5              1              4
6              1              5
7              1              7
```

Подскажите как записать в csv файл ключи. Сейчас в файл пишется в одну ячейку

[image: табличка после выполнения]

***Должно быть (без индексов)***

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну наверное указать `sep=;` при записи в файл.

Comment: @CrazyElf, не совсем вас понял

Comment: проблема не в csv, а в инструменте в котором вы его открываете. Он не понимает разделение через запятую. А убрать индексы это добавить аргумент index=False в метод to_csv()

Comment: @Alpensin, а можно как-то исправить? Принципиально важно, чтобы словарь остался без изменений

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы `Excel` правильно понимал столбцы, нужно указать разделитель `;`, а вывод индекса можно отключить.

```
z.to_csv(r"C:\\Users\\Users\\PyProj\\Script_check\\dict_of_right_transitions.csv",
         sep=';', index=False)
```